# SMS with Twilio Test Credential does not work

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio Test crredentials o send a sample SMS message to my phone number  which is already verified. When I run this script, it returns an SID and seems to work as expected only that I never receive the ext.. What am I missing?

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "AC3196c6a6fchha5de2c64a57e453e8e4b35"
auth_token = "fa1b7f6fdf3384ece5f5eda67cf7b42e28b"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
        to = "+12068515737",
        from_ = "+15005550006",
        body = "Jenny please?! I love you <3")
print(message.sid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[That is the expected result when using test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials). They are supposed to behave like real credentials, but never actually cause a message to be sent, or the call to be made or number to be bought. They are just for testing that the HTTP request was made correctly.

To send a message, you should use your real credentials. If you still have a trial account and a verified number, then you can send a message to that verified number using your trial account and it won't cost you anything. Only once you upgrade your account and add credit yourself will it cost to send an SMS message.

Let me know if that helps at all.